# docker-compose: access from docker container to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a service that runs inside a docker container. This service need to accesses the database that is run in another cluster (I use `kubectl port-forward` and after it I access database in `localhost:5432`)

Here is my `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - APP_PORT=8000 
      - DB_SERVER=localhost
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

It seems that redirection of port `5432` does not work as expected because connection to database fails inside the container. Could you help me to understand what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In current context, **localhost** is **api** container address. You have to set **DB_SERVER** for correct address. Your service and database has to be in the same docker network and then you can use internal docker address resolver. After that, you should set DB_SERVER=postgres. Another way, you can set DB_SERVER to your host address.

This is how you can define network in docker-compose:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network